# Sheet deformation under gravity

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, continuum-mechanics

When explaining space-time curvature in physics outreach, one often uses the analogy between space-time curvature and the deformation of a sheet (thus a 2d surface) which is topped with a mass $M$ (let's assume the mass is a point mass). My question is then

> What does the theory says about such deformation of a sheet? Can we compute such a deformation?

I believe that continuum mechanics can, but physics courses are too far for me, and I did not find the computation on the Internet.

Is it even possible to find the resulting metric on the (bent) sheet?

Comment: [There is an interesting article on this here](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/relativity-shock-experiments-reveal-that-deformed-rubber-sheet-is-not-like-spacetime-b8566ba5a110)

Comment: This is the [Middleton Langston paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.4848635) referred to in that article.

Comment: what is "vulgarization physics"? I am not familiar with that term.

Comment: @nielsnielsen this is "physics outreach" but in French, I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the sheet is homogenous & isotropic (i.e., it doesn't stretch more easily on one direction than another, and all points are equally stretchy), then the rubber sheet will form a [minimal surface:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface)  it will minimize its surface area assuming the boundary is held fixed.  If the surface can be expressed in the form $z = z(x,y)$, then an equivalent condition is that the function $z$ satisfies
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{z_x}{\sqrt{ 1 + z_x^2 + z_y^2}} \right) + 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \frac{z_y}{\sqrt{ 1 + z_x^2 + z_y^2}} \right) = 0
$$
where $z_x = \partial z /\partial x$ and $z_y = \partial z /\partial y$.  Note that in the limit $z_x, z_y \ll 1$, this is approximately equivalent to $\nabla^2 z = 0$.

Given the solution to this equation, the induced metric due to the surface's embedding in 3D space is
$$
ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + \left( z_x \, dx + z_y \, dy \right)^2 \\ = (1 + z_x^2) \, dx^2 + 2 z_x z_y \, dx \, dy + (1 + z_y^2) \, dy^2.
$$
If one wanted to, one could then calculate the Christoffel symbols for this metric, write out the geodesic equations, etc.

In practice, there are very few sets of boundary conditions for the "rubber sheet" that allow the first equation to be solved analytically, so numerical techniques and/or approximations (i.e., $z_x, z_y \ll 1$) must be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this seems like an equation of the sheet alone, isn't it? What happen if you put a mass $M$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

Comment: @JacquesMardot:  Not sure, but I suspect that there's a pressure term that would arise on the right-hand side.  (Note that a point mass might have problems, since the function $z(x,y)$ wouldn't have well-behaved derivatives there.)  If I have time, I'll do a bit more research on this later this week and figure out how it gets modified.

Comment: thank you! In fact, the article by Midleton and Langston did the computation using an energy method finding, where $r$ is the radius, and $z$ the height of the sheet, $z'(r) \sim C(M/r)^{1/3}$ where $C$ is some dimensional constant. From there one can find the associated metric which should be $ds^2 = dr^2 + dz^2 = (1+C(M/r)^{2/3})dr^2$, am I right?

Comment: Let us say that the sheet has zero mass, only bending because of the gravity of $M$. I have to admit that then I want to compare with the induced metric than Newtonian gravity would give on space (which I don't know how to find either).